# I want to make a clock(GUI program) via windows api, but the text on the clock doesn't change?

Tags: c++, windows

[image: Clock]

I want the text change as time changes like a clock, however, it doesn't change. I found that the text will change when I minimize or maximize the window.
I guess I should redraw the window, but I am new to windows api, anyone good advice?

This is the main.cpp code：

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    //....
}

void Paint(HWND hwnd, LPCTSTR txt)
{
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;

    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

    DrawText(hdc, txt, -1, &rect,
        DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

// Thread function
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFun(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)lpParameter;
    while (1)
    {
        string dateStr = Ticker::GetCurrentTimeStr();
        Paint(hwnd, dateStr.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFun, hwnd, 0, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You need to invalidate the clock for repainting whenever time changed.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That's a perfectly fine answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MSalters You are right. I added that to the existing answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002(v=vs.85).aspx) to tell the system the drawing area has changed.

---

*Edit*

Instead of creating a new thread, you can create a timer with `SetTimer` (see [example)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_timer) and respond to `WM_TIMER` message. Call `InvalidateRect` in response to `WM_TIMER`, to repaint the window every second.

Do all of the painting in response to `WM_PAINT`.

Use `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` only in response to `WM_PAINT`, don't use `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` elsewhere.

Comment: thks for your time and patience.